# Modular invariance of WZW CFT and weight lattice/coroot lattice

Tags: string-theory, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra

I am reading the big yellow Book "conformal field theory" by Francesco et al (see equation 14.312-14.315). I am confused with the modular transformation of the Theta function under modular $S$ transformation. The theta function action on $\hat{\xi}=-2\pi i (\zeta,\tau,t)$ is
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Theta_\lambda^{(k)}(\zeta,\tau,t)=e^{-2\pi ikt}\sum_{\alpha^\vee \in Q^\vee} e^{-2\pi ik(\alpha^\vee+\lambda/k,\zeta)}e^{i\pi k\tau |\alpha^\vee+\lambda/k|^2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $Q^\vee$ is coroot lattice. Under $S$ transformation
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Theta_\lambda^{(k)}((\frac{\zeta}{\tau},-\frac{1}{\tau},t+\frac{|\zeta|^2}{2\tau}))=(-\frac{i\tau}{k})^{r/2}\frac{e^{-2\pi ikt}}{vol(Q^\vee)}\sum_{p\in P} e^{-2\pi i(p,\zeta+\lambda/k)+i\pi|p|^2\tau/k}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $P$  is the weight lattice, the dual lattice is the coroot lattice $Q^\vee$.  Now separating summation over $P$ into
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{p\in P}f(p)=\sum_{\beta\in kQ^\vee}\sum_{\mu\in P/kQ^\vee}f(\beta^\vee +\mu)
\end{aligned}

The authors use the relation $Q^\vee\subset P$ to decompose the summation described in the last equation.  My question is that the root lattice is a subset of the weight lattice, $Q\subset P$. And the coroot lattice is not a subset of $P$. So why do the authors use the relation $Q^\vee\subset P$, which seems inconsistent?

(For su(n) algebra, the root lattice $Q$ is the same as coroot lattice $Q^\vee$, so it makes sense that $Q^\vee\subset P$. But for general Lie algebra $Q\neq Q^\vee$ )